# jQuery hover only works on 2nd hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, function

I'm new to jQuery and I am having an issue with my .hover function. When I hover over an image the first time, the animation does work, but when I mouse over it right after again it works fine. Thanks for any help. you can view a live example at zacknoblauch.com Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="home_post_box">


    <?php } ?>


        <?php the_post_thumbnail('home-image'); ?>

            <div class="home_post_text">

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p class="home_post_text_back">check it out >></p></a>

            </div><!--//home_post_text-->

    </div><!--//home_post_box-->
```

CSS:

```
.home_post_text {
background-color: #50D07D;
width: 320px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
color: #fff;
z-index: 10;
visibility: hidden;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

```
.home_post_box {
max-width: 320px;
max-height: 200px;
width: 320px;
height: 200px;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

jQuery:

```
 $(function(){
        $(".home_post_box").hover(function(){
            $(".home_post_text", this).stop().animate({top:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:1000});
    },

        function() {
            $(".home_post_text", this).stop().animate({top:"200px"},{queue:false,duration:1000});
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to declare a value for `top` in the css... At the moment it defaults to `auto` - and you cannot animate from `auto` to `0px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `visibility: hidden;` and add `top: 200px;` to .home_post_text.

```
.home_post_text {
background-color: #50D07D;
width: 320px;
height: 200px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
color: #fff;
z-index: 10;
text-decoration: none;    
//visibility: hidden;
top: 200px; }
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/viktorb/f24pZ/

Comment: Deleting my post as your answer was 30 seconds faster than mine, and way more concise!

Answer (score -1):

Use closest for Div selection

```
closest( selector  )
    .closest( selector )
    .closest( selector [, context] )
    .closest( jQuery object )
    .closest( element )
closest( selectors [ , context ]  )
```

### .closest( selectors [, context] )

$(this).closest("div.first-div").find("div.inside-div");